# Plone 4.2 permissions.zcml ignored or fails

Tags: permissions, plone, genericsetup

When I try to include a permissions.zcml in my project, with this line on configure.zcml

```
 <include package="Products.CMFCore" file="permissions.zcml"
       xmlns:zcml="http://namespaces.zope.org/zcml"
       zcml:condition="have plone-41" />
```

or just this line

```
  <include package="Products.CMFCore"/ >
```

it fails to load and raises errors, when processing the rolemap.xml.

When I try to include the file with

```
<include file="permissions.zcml">
```

I get

```
ConfigurationError: ('Unknown directive', u'http://namespace.zope.org/zope', u'permission')
```

but when I write the permission declaration in configure.zcml it gets properly processed. I tried several include package statements. The dexterity manual states, that with zope 2.12 (using 2.13) collective.autopermission is no longer needed for this job.

What could I miss?

**Edit I**

my [permissions.zcml](http://pastebin.com/KA645ajR)

@Martijn Pieters: Zope version is: 2.13.16

Comment: Could you include your full `permissions.zcml`? I think you are missing a namespace declaration.

Comment: The `permission` directive is defined in the `AccessControl` `meta.zcml` file; not sure how your `zcml` file is being included without the `AccessControl` meta having been loaded. What Zope version is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was indeed missing a namespace and and the include of AccessControl. This permissions.zcml
does the job.

```
<configure
xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
xmlns:meta="http://namespaces.zope.org/meta"
xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"
i18n_domain="dotted.name">

<includeDependencies package="." />
<include package="AccessControl" file="meta.zcml" />
<include package="Products.CMFCore" file="permissions.zcml"/>    

 </configure>
```